# System Center 2012 Security

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2, system-center

I installed the entire System Center 2012 Suite and I run the Database on it's own machine. During installation I noticed you could use specific user(s) on the install and setup for each of the applications.

Is it in my best interest to create domain accounts and fine tune them for each area or stick to just using the Domain Administrator account and/or the Built-In accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Domain admin accoutns for service accounts. if the service is compromised then your domain admin account could be as well. I would create separate user accounts for each service and give them the rights they require for their role.

What Server OS are you using?

there is some good advice in this blog:
http://www.systemcenter.ninja/2012/05/system-cennter-2012-service-accounts.html